# Sorting a list of integers in C before printing them

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I need to print my final array elements in a sorted order.
I have made a group of three elements and I am finding the largest element of the group. I need to display the list in a sorted order.

This is the relevant pieces of my code:

```
#define MAX 9
void display(); //Display the element of array
int array[MAX]; //Array for Storing MAX element

//Function for displaying  elements
void display()
{
    int read_counter;
    for(read_counter = 0; read_counter < MAX; read_counter++)
    {
        printf("\n Elements are %d\t",array[read_counter]);
    }
}
```

How can I sort and print the elemnts of `array` ?

Comment: Do you need the actually array to be sorted or you just need to display it sorted while keeping it as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [qsort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) with a `compare` function:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

And then use it to sort your array before printing:

```
qsort (array, 3, sizeof(int), compare);
```

If you are handling *very large* or *very small* numbers and are afraid of an overflow situation, use this `compare` method instead:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
  int va = *(const int*) a;
  int vb = *(const int*) b;
  return (va > vb) - (va < vb);
}
```

Comment: `*(int *)a - *(int *)b` can overflow for some combinations of values (e.g, subtracting a big positive value from a negative one).  That gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter you are absolutely right. I added an edit to address that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the array and then display it.

If you don't want the actual array to change you can keep the sorted array in an intermediate temporary array.

Do something like:

```
#define MAX 9
void display(); //Display the element of array
int array[MAX]; //Array for Storing MAX element

//Function for displaying  elements
void display()
{
 int min,i,j,tempArray[MAX],temp;

 //copy into temporary array
 for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
  tempArray[i] = array[i];

 //sort temporary array (basic selection sort)
 for(i=0;i<MAX-1;i++)
 {
  min = i;
  for(j=i+1;j<MAX;j++)
  {
   if(tempArray[min] > tempArray[j] )
   {
    min = j;
   }
    //swap min with current if current is not already min
    if(i != min)
    {
     temp = tempArray[i];
     tempArray[i] = tempArray[min];
     tempArray[min] = temp;
    }
  }
 }
    int read_counter;
    for(read_counter = 0; read_counter < MAX; read_counter++)
    {
        printf("\n Elements are %d\t",tempArray[read_counter]);
    }
}
```